# The script I am using to archive gmail messages to drive is not working due to the Docslist change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have been using "archive to drive" script, today it stopped working.

I changed the script from Docslist to DriveApp;

However I don't understand how to resolve the two last lines of script.

Please help.

```
/**
 * Create a Google Drive Folder
 *
 * @param {String} baseFolder name of the base folder
 * @param {String} folderName name of the folder
 * @return {Folder} the folder object created representing the new folder 
 */
function createDriveFolder(baseFolder, folderName) {    
var baseFolderObject = DriveApp.getFolder(baseFolder);
return baseFolderObject.createFolder(folderName);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of getting the folder object from `baseFolder`, you can directly create a sub folder in `baseFolder` as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFolder(String)).

```
folder.createFolder(name)
```

Hope that helps!